# how do I keep the elements displayed if the filtering is not done (the codes don't match)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am filtering some objects by their codes. The problem is that when I type a code that does not correspond with my object code I got nothing( which is normal because the codes don't match). How can i keep the objects displayed if the codes don't match? Another problem is that if the codes match and I erase the code from my search bar, I still got my searched item, but I want to have all the objects back.How could I do this? Any tips are welcome

```
    enterKeyPress={code => {
        // this.request(value);

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.filter(
                item => item.code === parseInt(code, 10)
            ),
        });
    }}
    {this.state.items.map((itm, idx) => (
          <List.RowWrapper key={idx}>
              <List.RowLink href="#" direction="column">
                  <List.RowHeader>
                      <ImgSize
                          src={`${settings(
                              "public.s3_images.issues"
                          )}${itm.images[0]}`}
                      />

                      <List.RowTitle>
                          {itm.tags[0]}
                      </List.RowTitle>
                      <List.RowTime color="textDisabled"></List.RowTime>
                      <List.RowArrow />
                  </List.RowHeader>
              </List.RowLink>
          </List.RowWrapper>
      ))}
```

Comment: You need to keep a separate array in `state` that contains the filtered items so you don't lose the unfiltered one.

Comment: Also...regarding erasing the search content, you could use `onChange` event which will trigger the function that you link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
enterKeyPress=code => {
    // this.request(value);
    if(items.includes(code))
    {
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.filter(
                item => item.code === parseInt(code, 10)
            ),
        }); 
    }
}
```